# PHP PDO mutiple select, multiple conditions

Tags: php, mysql, select, pdo

How can i fill my array with PDO statement which have multiple conditions?

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * 
                        FROM the_table 
                        WHERE stmt1 = '$value1' 
                          AND stmt2 = '$value2' 
                        ORDER BY sent_date");
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

So, this works, but I need the of the table data from my table, because I going to get only the first statement values. What I mean? If my first value (like $value1) is out the selecting change to the second statement's value (like $value2). And i will get all of my table data where exists $value1 and $value2
I need the values an array like $row

Sorry for this composition :D.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not how you use prepared statements.. I also don't know what your question is.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: How can I fill my array with 2 conditions. This is the question.

Comment: What does this query give you? I don't understand 1. `I need the of the table data from my table` 2. `If my first value (like $value1) is out the selecting change to the second statement's value (like $value2).` 3. `I need the values an array like $row`.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you would prepare your query like that

```
<?php

/* insert code for database connexion here */

$value1 = 'something';
$value2 = 'whatever';

/* The query itself */
$query = $connexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM the_table WHERE stmt1 = :first AND stmt2 = :second ORDER BY sent_date');

/* Now we add the wanted values to our query */
$query->execute([
    'first' => $value1,
    'second' => $value2
]);

$result = $query->fetchAll();
```

Do not forget to check if the result is what your expected.